# GHCi cannot find documentations

Tags: haskell, ghci, ghcup

I installed Haskell on Windows using ghcup. While using GHCi, ":doc name" answers back with an error message. Some examples are:

**ghci> :doc (++)**
ghc-9.2.5.exe: Can't find any documentation for GHC.Base.
This is probably because the module was compiled without '-haddock',
but it's also possible that the module contains no documentation.

Try re-compiling with '-haddock'.

---

**ghci> :doc Sum**
ghc-9.2.5.exe: Can't find any documentation for Data.Semigroup.Internal.
This is probably because the module was compiled without '-haddock',
but it's also possible that the module contains no documentation.

Try re-compiling with '-haddock'.

---

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can't reproduce. In linux `ghc-9.2.7` the `:doc` command does work... Could you try installing that version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary distributions (“bindists”) of GHC 9.2.5, and several earlier versions, were missing support for `:doc`. I believe this was fixed in 9.2.6, since it’s mentioned in the [GHC 9.2.6 release notes](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.2.6/docs/html/users_guide/9.2.6-notes.html#build-system-and-packaging). You should be able to run `ghcup install ghc 9.2` to get the latest 9.2 patch release (currently 9.2.7).

I happened to notice that it started working on my macOS machine (for the first time!) when I updated to 9.4.2.

Comment: Upgraded GHC distro and it is working great now.